# how to call class name in python?

Tags: python-2.7

self.**class**.**name** represents the name of the class, if I do

```
class myClass(object):
   def showname(self):
     print 'My name is', self.__class__.__name__
```

this will give me the name of the class
but

```
    class myClass(object):
         def __init__(self):
             pass
             ...

    """now I want to call the class by using self.__class__.__name__ so 
    I dont have to type the class name in function_B()"""

    def someFunctions():
    return function_A().function_B(self.__class__.__name__)
```

then this gave me an error saying the self is not defined? any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: Your code doesn't make your question very clear.  Especially since your first class appears to do exactly what you want it to do?  Remember that `self` is a local variable inside of a method - if you try to reference it directly outside of that method it won't be defined.  Instead do it the way you did in the first place.

Comment: yeah, I think that was the problem because the second method does not belong to the first class...

Comment: Maybe you can edit this to more clearly show what you want to happen?  For example, you give us no info on what is in `function_A` or `function_B`, or what the expected output should be.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to indent, and self as a parameter

```
    class myClass(object):
        def __init__(self):
             pass
         ...

"""now I want to call the class by using self.__class__.__name__ so 
I dont have to type the class name in function_B()"""

        def someFunctions(self):
           return function_A().function_B(self.__class__.__name__)
```

Now you can test

```
x=myClass()
x.someFunctions()
```

and self is sent to someFunctions

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention, the last def does not belong to the same class. So I think that is the root cause ... I am not sure how to fix it..

Comment: please be precise : what classes did you define, which class name do you want to send to functionB. You obviously need to send the object to someFunctions to get its class name

Comment: well, thank you for your reply, basically what I wanted to get out of this was to just reference the class name once, and when I call the class to do other job, I only have to use self.__class__.__name__ without have to reference the class name again. however, it is not possible for me not to reference it again regardless what I am planning to do, so I decided to drop it and just write the class name there for the simplicity. (I would have to create an instance of this class for other class to use it)